# Batch script (bat or cmd) - extra spaces before ampersand (or automatically escape ampersand)

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, escaping

**Note:** I understand the `^` symbol can be used to escape `&` symbol in batch scripts. But I need the escaping to be done **automatically**, as the paths are constructed at run-time. The sample script below is merely to show the problem and it is **not** the actual script. *Please read my explanation after script output.*

For some reason, commands in a batch script do not behave well with the ampersand (`&`) symbol in the path.

Assume you have a `test.cmd` or `test.bat` script as follows:

```
set TEST=A E
echo %TEST%

set TEST="A E"
echo %TEST%

set TEST=AE
echo %TEST%

set TEST="AE"
echo %TEST%

set TEST=A & E
echo %TEST%

set TEST="A & E"
echo %TEST%

set TEST=A&E
echo %TEST%

set TEST="A&E"
echo %TEST%
```

Here is the output:

```
C:\>set TEST=A E
C:\>echo A E
A E

C:\>set TEST="A E"
C:\>echo "A E"
"A E"

C:\>set TEST=AE
C:\>echo AE
AE

C:\>set TEST="AE"
C:\>echo "AE"
"AE"

C:\>set TEST=A   & E
'E' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\>echo A
A

C:\>set TEST="A & E"
C:\>echo "A & E"
"A & E"

C:\>set TEST=A  & E
'E' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\>echo A
A

C:\>set TEST="A&E"
C:\>echo "A&E"
"A&E"
```

Notice how the script parser adds two extra spaces before the ampersand (`&`) symbol when the string is not double-quoted. It also breaks up `A&E` into `A& E` before adding the two spaces, resulting in `A  & E`

**In a real-life situation,** this causes problems when appending paths containing the ampersand (`&`) symbol in folder names to the `PATH` variable. Even an existing set of folder paths in `PATH` when referenced as `set PATH=C:\Another\Folder;%PATH%` gets this issue.

It occurs both in *Command Prompt* and in *PowerShell*. I have tried `enableDelayedExpansion` but it does not help.

Why does it behave this way? It looks like it is because `&` is used in Batch script to join two commands? If yes, how do I ensure it's escaped ***automatically*** (because the `PATH` value is automatically constructed at run-time so I cannot escape with `^` - the path is **not** hard-coded in the batch script).

Currently the only workaround I found (as shown above) is to enclose the whole string in double quotes (`"`). For the existing value of a `PATH` variable, I think I will need to parse the value in a loop and add quotes to every folder path in it. Is there any other (perhaps easier) workaround or permanent solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable delayed expansion and try this:

```
Set "test1=c:\file&folder\"
Set "test2=!test1!currentPath"
echo !test2!
```

For environment variables like `PATH` that contain `&` in their existing value:

```
set PATH=C:\Another\Folder;!PATH!
```

Comment: I need it done automatically at run-time, not hard-coded in the batch script, because it's dealing with environment variables.

Comment: You're right. This works for environment variables as well (not just paths coded into the script). The magic is in using `!` instead of `%` to enclose variable names. Thank you!

Comment: I have used your solution to fix the script in [msysgit issue 245](https://github.com/msysgit/git/issues/245).