# How to use '&' as an argument in windows commandline

Tags: node.js, cmd, command-line

I've written a nodejs package that allows you to make HTTP(S) requests from the Windows terminal, so you type in something like `http get https://stackoverflow.com` and bam, there's the response. Something I've noticed, however, is that using an ampersand (&) in a URL breaks the command. It seems like this is a feature built in to let you run multiple commands in one line. So if you run:
`http get https://api.example.com/getinfo?request=example&apikey=APIKEY`, then it makes a request to `https://api.example.com/getinfo?request=example`, and then tries to run 'apikey' as a command, yielding the error: `'apikey' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
Is there a way I can get around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch script (bat or cmd) - extra spaces before ampersand (or automatically escape ampersand)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829908/batch-script-bat-or-cmd-extra-spaces-before-ampersand-or-automatically-esca)

Comment: @tripleee, thanks, but my cli tool is written in nodejs and so this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this works on Windows as well, but on Linux you can put a string in single or double quotes. Then the string is given to the application without being interpreted by the terminal (except for replacing environment variables with $ in double-quotes). This is also useful if you want to pass an argument with whitespaces in it.

So, try

`http get "https://api.example.com/getinfo?request=example&apikey=APIKEY"`

or

`http get 'https://api.example.com/getinfo?request=example&apikey=APIKEY'`

Comment: The quoting rules in Windows `cmd` are quite different, and basically insane.

Comment: Weirdly, this only works with double quotes, but still better than not working at all!